# Same site answering to two domain names

Tags: domain-mapping

I need to figure out a way to get a Wordpress site to completely answer (including pages) to two different domain names.

Currently, I'm using DNN for various professional sites in which they started life as domainX.org and now answer either domainX.org OR domainY.org. This includes all the underlying content. domainX.org/folder/pagename works exactly the same way domainY.org/folder/pagename only the domain name in the URL in the address field of the browser is different. DNN easily allows for this using domain alias settings.

I've gone to try to do this with a Wordpress site today and I find out it natively does not have these capabilities. The hoster of the Wordpress site, Blue Host doesn't know how to do this either, so they were no help.

I'm assuming there is a plugin that might allow for this functionality, but I hesitate to try plugins unless they come recommended.

Has anyone else run up against this need and what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

On the surface this is quite trivial, WP discerns domain from current configuration and it can be defined in config file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

This can easily be done *dynamically*, depending on *current* domain being requested from PHP context. As long as domains map to same IP and location on server.

Note that duplicate content is considered universally bad idea for SEO. From that point of view it would be preferable to pick one domain name as canonical and 301 redirect another one to it (which is usually outside/unrelated to WP).

Comment: Cool, I will try this approach.  Can I add a comma and then the second domain?

This is a newsletter site that we're not concerned with search, believe it or not.  It gets it's traffic from our other sites and is only topical to a very small geographic area.  Since we link to it from our other sites, I was looking to preserve those links while changing the domain name to a sub of our corporate domain.

Comment: No, as per answer you will need to add some custom PHP logic that figures out actual domain of request and registers constants accordingly.